# Drag and drop: Submit a File from drag and drop with regular form?

Tags: javascript, forms, html, drag-and-drop

I've got a form that uploads files (post), with a few `<input type='file'/>` tags, and I want users to be able to drag and drop files onto the web page, eg, from their desktop. When they do this, the files should be added to the form as file input tags

It shouldn't matter where they drop it on the page (and I am already handling this drop event on the page)

When I have the File object for the file they dragged, how can I add it to the form as an `<input type='file'/>`? Or, is there another way to add it to the form so it'll be sent when the form is submitted, as if it was selected using the file input itself?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You could try Uploadify > http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

It has an API that you can call with javascript.